# VB6 How to Make a Floating Window TOP Most

Tags: winapi, vb6, popup

I just wondered how the [Google Input Tool for Windows](http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/windows/) is running.. while dragging the little google popup window (which gives the language suggestions), the notepad won't lost focus...

I tried the Same style of Window which,

- Floats on top most on any other windows.
- Applied Drop Shadow.
- Gets the Text Caret Position from any window and moved dynamically with the Cursor.

Now the problem is, When i Click and Drag my window, the Notepad / any application loses its focus and current focus is on my little popup window.

But the `Google Input Tool` , while dragging it, the notepad won't loses its focus..

Here, I want to achieve my floating popup window must not have focus .. and the target application should not lose focus while I am touching my popup window..

What windows VB6 API is used to achieve this..

Thank you Very much for Watching.... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Windows API code (put it in a module)

```
  Option Explicit
  Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
  Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
  Public Const FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
  Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
  Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2

  Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowPos"  _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
        ByVal x As Long, _
        ByVal y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal wFlags As Long  ) As Long

  Public Function SetTopMostWindow(hwnd As Long, Topmost As Boolean) _
     As Long

     If Topmost = True Then 'Make the window topmost
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, _
           0, FLAGS)
     Else
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, _
           0, 0,FLAGS)
        SetTopMostWindow = False
     End If
  End Function
```

In usage, this will set Form1 topmost:

```
SetTopMostWindow Form1.hwnd, True
```

(from the first result when Googling *vb6 window topmost*, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184297)

Comment: Yes, Thank you @Dan Verdolino ... but this is the actual code I am using in my form .. as well i added `SWP_NOACTIVATE` option to the `FLAGS` too.. but didn't worked.. The Form did getting the Focus when i clicked on the form.. and the NOTEPAD is losing the focus...

Comment: @Gokul I didn't realize you meant another application of which you don't have control. Do you need this to work only for Notepad or for *any* other application?

Comment: not only on notepad.. any application which has textbox input.. this floating window floats below the textbox of any application and uses the keyboard hook to get keys and modify the keys send it to currently focused that application... hope you understand,  this is similarly like google input tool.. only problem is my floating form should not acquire focus (Activation) even it is clicked.. at the same time the target application should not loss the Focus..

Comment: thank you. make sure to call this function on form initialization and this is how you call it: SetTopMostWindow frm2.hwnd, True . with no brackets in vb6. this is how it works for me.